# Cannot include css in application in rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm using rails 4
and ruby 2.1.5
And I generate controllers rails generate .scss file for me I write specific code in css but it doesn't gets include in application?

I link it with

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'name of css' %>
```

and I do this in html.erb file in views

What should I do ?

If this is silly sorry I'm new to rails..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the CSS in the *layout*:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.css
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "name_of_css" %>
```

This will call the CSS in the `<head>` tag of your HTML page.

If you want to call `css` conditionally, you'll have to set it in the `stylesheet_link_tag` declaration:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, ("tester" if controller_name == "tests") %>
```